# How to send RST manually with a custom server?

Tags: tcp, tcpserver

I am trying to debug a scenario, and for that I want the http server to close the connection via RST. Right now it is doing a graceful close with fin/ack.

Is there any way I can manually send a RST packet to close the connection as part of the current stream? may be a simple custom server?

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming it is your own code, call `setsockopt()` with `option=SO_LINGER` and the `linger` structure set to `l_onoff=1` and `l_linger=0`, and then close the socket. Any outbound data that is still buffered will be lost, which includes data already sent but not acknowledged.

Use this only for testing. It is insecure and unkind.

If it isn't your code in the server, write a client that does a GET of a large resource and closes the connection without reading any of the response.

Source: W.R. Stevens *et al., Unix Network Programming,* vol 1, 3rd edition, p.202.

Comment: Setting `l_onoff = 0` with any value for `l_linger` would do as well, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Asblarf No it wouldn't. There are three behaviours. This is the only one that causes an RST. What you suggest is the default behaviour, an asynchronous orderly close.

Comment: OK, thanks (just had a look at `net/ipv4/tcp.c` in the Linux Kernel and it does what you say. It all checks.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @EJP, that was what I was looking for. Appreciate your quick response. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For reference, code snippet for the setsockopt() with linger. Thanks to @EJB for the help.
With this option set, the server closes the connection with RST.

```
...
     struct linger so_linger;

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");

     so_linger.l_onoff = 1;
     so_linger.l_linger = 0;
     setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &so_linger, sizeof(so_linger));
...
```